# Encoding error Python3.5

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

So I'm encountering a strange encoding error in Python3.5, I'm reading a string consisting html-data, and I'm handling the string like this :

```
def parseHtml(self,url):
        r  = requests.get(self.makeUrl())
        data = r.text.encode('utf-8').decode('ascii', 'ignore')
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')
```

The error happens when I'm trying to print the following:

```
def extractTable(self):
        table = self.soup.findAll("table", { "class" : "messageTable" })
        print(table)
```

I have checked my locale, and tried various variations of encode / decode as stated in previous similar posts on SO. The strangest thing (for me) is that the script works flawlessly on a different machine and on my laptop. But on my Windows Machine (using cygwin to a remote server) and on my Ubuntu install it simply wont run and gives me:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa0' in position 1273: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: What is this, there is no `unicode` in Python 3.5!

Comment: You're running your code in 2.7, data cannot have a Unicode BOM after decode with ignore, and it would throw exceptions everywhere on Python 3.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20

Comment: @AnttiHaapala My bad, the unicode thing was my last attempt before posting. I have edited the sample back to how it originally was. Running successfully on some computers.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I moved the file from the remote server to my local-machine and it executed perfectly. I then checked my sys.stdout.encoding :

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'ANSI_X3.4-1968'
```

Clearly something was wrong, so I ended up exporting :

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
```

And voìla!